# selenium bot does not work when you press the bot

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm currently creating a selenium bot to create a bot for entering in kahoots.
The problem is when i enter the code and I try to automatically write the nickname in the textfield the script gives me this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcovinciguerra/Github/Python/Selenium _Kahoot_bot/a.py", line 32, in <module>
    test_a()
  File "/Users/marcovinciguerra/Github/Python/Selenium _Kahoot_bot/a.py", line 24, in test_a
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "nickname").click()
  File "/Users/marcovinciguerra/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/marcovinciguerra/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/marcovinciguerra/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="nickname"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.79)
```

The code of the script is the following:

```
def test_a():
driver.get("https://kahoot.it/")
driver.set_window_size(1512, 945)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "game-input").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "game-input").send_keys("14988")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "game-input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nickname").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nickname").send_keys("vinci0000")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-jJEJSO").click()
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-jJEJSO")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
test_a()

And the textfield i wanna enter the text is the following:

```
<input name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" maxlength="15" id="nickname" data-functional-selector="username-input" class="sc-fWSCIC hEgquS" autocomplete="off" dir="ltr" value="jjj">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to error trace, your issue is not finding the element in page. If that element is not in an iframe, or in a shadow root element and the ID attribute is correct, you should be able to locate it with:

```
text_field = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "nickname")))
```

You also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And lastly, Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

It would be wise to wait out the rest of the elements you are trying to locate, to make sure they are loaded and interactable.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML provided:

```
<input name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Nickname" maxlength="15" id="nickname" data-functional-selector="username-input" class="sc-fWSCIC hEgquS" autocomplete="off" dir="ltr" value="jjj">
```

I don't see any such issues in the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used, i.e.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nickname")
```

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a character sequence to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *ID*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "nickname"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#nickname"))).send_keys("vinci0000")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='nickname']"))).send_keys("vinci0000")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```